# Is $\mu([0,x] \cap A)$ differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset [0, \infty]$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Define for $x \geq 0$, $f(x):=\mu([0,x] \cap A)$. Is $f$ differentiable almost everywhere?

---

Here is my attempt:

For each $a < b$, we have that $f(b) = \mu([0,b] \cap A) = \mu(([0,a] \cup [a,b]) \cap A) \geq \mu([0,a] \cap A) = f(a)$. Hence $f$ is monotonic in $[a,b]$. So we can conclude that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $[0,b]$, for each $b > 0$.
I'm not sure how to continue to prove the statement about $[0,\infty]$. Any clues?

Comment: How do we conclude $f$ is differentiable a.e on that interval. Do we even know if $f$ is continuous? I remember doing this question (almost exactly the same) when I took he introductory course, and my memory fails me and I cannot remember how to prove it, but I faintly remember using the fact that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)= \mu(A)$

Comment: @JihoonKang [If $f$ is a monotonic function, then $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Some_basic_applications_and_results)

Comment: @Adayah thank you - I actually was not aware of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've proven in particular that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set

$$A_n = \{ x \in [0, n] : f \text{ is not differentiable at } x \}$$

has measure $0$. Now can you write

$$A = \{ x \in [0, \infty) : f \text{ is not differentiable at } x \}$$

in terms of $A_n$? What is the measure of $A$?

Comment: Got it, thanks.